# How do I get a TestNG report to show console output?

Tags: testng

How do I get my TestNG report to show a link to the console output from the report?  I've seen TestNG do it before but a project I am working on right now isn't showing any of the output and I can't find any information anywhere that says how to turn it on.   I tried setting the "verbose" option in the testng.xml suite tag but that didn't have any effect at all.

Comment: Just System.out.println right now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

please use below line to show console log while writing test using testNG.

```
Reporter.log( "Message", true );
```

Comment: This works but I think there are certain scopes where, if you call this, you wont see output, depending on where you call it from. I'm still trying to understand why.

Comment: You can use Log4J for your projects logging, its good to print logs on console or in a file. if you want to print logs in TestNG report you can always use Reporter.log(""). Log4J is very easy to configure with the help of xml property file.

Comment: I'm not so sure that Log4j output would actually show in the TestNG log, without using Reporter.log(), would it?  I was looking at Log4j 2.0 a little and it looks nicer than Logback.

Comment: Log4j would not show logs in TestNG Log/Report but its better to use log4j for logging in seperate log file or console. It gives you more options for logging compared to TestNG Logging.

Comment: @djangofan, if you log directly from a test method it appears that `Reporter.log` works fine. Not sure whether that behavior is a bug or as intended.

Comment: I wrote a LogManager class and created methods like logInfo , logError. Inside these methods , I called log4j log info method and Reporter.log method...which solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to do Reporter.log to get anything in the report.  If you want to also print to console, it gives you an overloaded method to do that as well.

Answer (score -1):

Which version of TestNG are you using? I have 6.8.6 and I get a report with the console output for each testcase.

Comment: I use 6.8.7 :  https://github.com/djangofan/testng-dataprovider-xstream-xml/blob/master/pom.xml